# Software Center: invalid or out of range for property 'value' of type 'gint

Tags: software-center

hey guys so my software center won't install any apps, and its making my entire computer freeze this is what it says when i type software-center

```
lacy@lacy:~$ software-center
2013-11-10 15:47:13,139 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-11-10 15:47:13,955 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2013-11-10 15:47:13,957 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2013-11-10 15:47:13,993 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py', 51, 'find_module')'
2013-11-10 15:47:13,992 - root - ERROR - Could not find any typelib for LaunchpadIntegration
2013-11-10 15:47:14,207 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:532: Warning: value "101.000000" of type 'gdouble' is invalid or out of range for property 'value' of type 'gint'
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
2013-11-10 15:47:29,480 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/utils.py', 271, 'get_title_from_html')'
2013-11-10 15:47:29,480 - root - WARNING - failed to parse: '<div style="background-color: #161513; width:1680px; height:200px;">
<div style="background: url('/site_media/exhibits/2013/09/AAMFP_Leaderboard_700x200_1.jpg') top left no-repeat; width:700px; height:200px;"></div>
</div>' ('ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 70: ordinal not in range(128))
2013-11-10 15:47:45,309 - softwarecenter.db.utils - INFO - software-center-agent finished with status 0
/usr/bin/software-center:184: Warning: value "101.000000" of type 'gdouble' is     invalid or out of range for property 'value' of type 'gint'
  Gtk.main()
lacy@lacy:~$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems like some files are missing, try to uninstall it and re-install it again:

**Uninstall**

```
sudo apt-get remove software-center
```

**Re-install software center**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Comment: Remove and auto remove?

Comment: This should answer the question but, just FYI, "autoremove XX" will remove the program and any other unused programs after XX is uninstalled making using both remove and autoremove redundant.

Comment: got it, going to edit that

Comment: Hey thanks man, I hope that reputation helps ;)

Comment: This doesn't work, I'm posting anew question about this